# Question on the proof of the First Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading Burton's "Introduction to Modern Abstract Algebra", and I'm a bit confused about the proof of the First Isomorphism Theorem. I have looked at the various posts regarding this theorem, but still remain confused. There is a lot of traffic on this subject, so I hope this post is not redundant. Also, please excuse the length of my post, which must surely reflect my misunderstanding of the proof.

In my text book, the Fundamental Theorem is proved in two steps. The text assumes that we have an onto homomorphism $f : G \to G^\prime$ for the groups $(G,*)$ and $(G^\prime,\circ)$, so that $f(G)=G^\prime$. It is not assumed that $f$ is one-to-one.

- **Theorem 2-46** (Factor Theorem). Let $(H,*)$ be a normal subgroup of $(G,*)$ such that $H \subseteq {\rm ker} f$. Then there exists a unique homomorphism $\bar f : G/H \to G^\prime$ (called the induced mapping) with the property $f = \bar f \circ {\rm nat}_H$.

Here the natural isomorphism ${\rm nat}_H : G \to G/H$ is defined as usual by ${\rm nat}_H(a) = a * H \in G/H$ for any $a \in G$. The induced mapping $\bar f : G/H \to G^\prime$ is defined by $\bar f(a * H) = f(a)$. The assumption $H \subseteq {\rm ker} f$ is required for $\bar f$ to be well defined, in the sense that $\bar f$ doesn't depend upon the representative $a \in G$ of the coset $a * H \in G/H$. That is to say, if $a * H = b * H$,  then $f(a)= f(b)$, so that $\bar f(a * H) = \bar f(b * H)$.

I have no problems with the proof of Theorem 2-46.  The text then presents a corollary to Theorem 2-46 which states the following.

- **Corollary**. The function $\bar f$ is one-to-one iff ${\rm ker} f \subseteq H$.

The homomoprohism $\bar f$ is one-to-one iff ${\rm ker} \bar f = \{ H \}$ (since $H$ is the identity element of $G/H$), and the strategy of the proof is to establish this equality. The corollary runs through an argument showing that

(1) ${\rm ker} \bar f = {\rm nat}_H({\rm ker} f)$,

and I have no problem following this argument. My problem is in the last two lines of the proof. The corollary goes on to show that:

(2) ${\rm nat}_H({\rm ker}f) = H$.

(3) Condition (2) is equivalent to the inclusion ${\rm ker}f \subseteq H$ (which proves the corollary).

My first confusion is that it seems to me that condition (2) should actually read ${\rm nat}_H({\rm ker} f) = \{H\}$. This is because ${\rm nat}_H({\rm ker} f)$ should be a subset of $G/H$; but $H$ is an elemnt of $G/H$, while $\{H\} \subseteq G/H$. Am I correct in thinking that this must be a typo or an abuse of notion in the text? My next confusion lies in assertion (3). I just don't follow this. My final confusion is the statement of the Corollary itself. Since we must assume that $H \subseteq {\rm ker} f$ for $\bar f$ to be well defined, wouldn't it be more proper to state that $\bar f$ is one-to-one iff ${\rm ker}f = H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\mathrm{nat}_H(\ker f) = \{H\}$ seems to be what is intended. (What this is really saying is that $\mathrm{nat}_H(\ker f)$ is the trivial group.)
2. If $\ker f \subseteq H$, then we have $\mathrm{nat}_H(h) = H$ for every $h \in \ker f$. So $\mathrm{nat}_H(\ker f) = \{H\}$. I'll leave the other direction for you to work out.
3. I haven't looked at the book, so I'm not exactly sure what the author is intending here. But you seem to be correct since the map $\bar{f}$ only makes sense if $H \subseteq \ker f$.

Comment: This makes sense now. In (2), don't you mean ${\rm nat}_H({\rm ker} f) = \{ H \}$?

Comment: Yes, I made the same mistake the author did haha.